# Integration Test on Membership Providers

Tags: c#, integration-testing, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I was attempting to do an Integration Test on the Membership Provider... It looks like this:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTestMembershipProvider
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Are_There_Membership_Users()
    {
        // Arrange
        MembershipUserCollection users = Membership.GetAllUsers();

        //Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(users.Count > 0);
    }
}
```

why might I be getting the following outcome?

```
Test Name:  Are_There_Membership_Users
Test FullName:  Something.UnitTests.Controllers.UnitTestMembershipProvider.Are_There_Membership_Users
Test Source:    c:\Users\James\Source\Workspaces\Something\Something.UnitTests\Controllers\UnitTestMembershipProvider.cs : line 12
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00.0298722

Result Message: 
Test method Something.UnitTests.Controllers.UnitTestMembershipProvider.Are_There_Membership_Users threw exception: 
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\App_Data' is denied.
Result StackTrace:  
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String path, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path)
   at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.CreateMdfFile(String fullFileName, String dataDir, String connectionString)
   at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.EnsureDBFile(String connectionString)
   at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.GetConnection(String connectionString, Boolean revertImpersonation)
   at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.GetAllUsers(Int32 pageIndex, Int32 pageSize, Int32& totalRecords)
   at System.Web.Security.Membership.GetAllUsers(Int32 pageIndex, Int32 pageSize, Int32& totalRecords)
   at System.Web.Security.Membership.GetAllUsers()
   at Something.UnitTests.Controllers.UnitTestMembershipProvider.Are_There_Membership_Users() in c:\Users\James\Source\Workspaces\Something\Something.UnitTests\Controllers\UnitTestMembershipProvider.cs:line 14
```

Comment: The error is in the error message. Also.. this is an _Integration Test_.. since without mocking your MembershipProvider will hit a database. Small details like that matter :P

Comment: (This is the second test I have written in my life.. so, yea I guess I haven't quite understood.. hehe).. Does this mean that such a test can sit inside the main application rather than the UnitTesting area? I realise how trivial this test is.. it was mostly a practice case.

Comment: Perfect integration test. It should be in the Integration Test area, with a config that has a connection string which talk to the membership db. I think it is 'very' important you separate them out from your Unit Test project.